# Is it possible to configure handler interceptors without giving controller name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want an interceptor to be called for all the url's with pattern /user/display/* and don't want to configure the controller name to which these url's map to.

Spring documentation gives the following example

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="officeHoursInterceptor"/>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>
                 /user/display/*=editAccountFormController
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

In my case i don't want to give editAccountFormController.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify interceptors independently of the controllers using `<mvc:interceptors>`, e.g.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mapping path="/user/display/*"/>
        <bean class="com.x.y.MyInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

See [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-interceptors) for more detail.

Comment: oh gosh! I missed it in the docs. That's great! Thanks skaffman